# Start ignite in persistent store mode and query using sqlline console

Tags: ignite, persistent-storage, sqlline

I am starting ignite db in persistent mode with following configuration -

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
    -->
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
     <!-- Enabling Apache Ignite Persistent Store. -->
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This configuration is in `config/default-config.xml` file

After that I am starting sqlline console using -

> sqlline.sh --color=true --verbose=true -u
>   jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/

In the console when I am executing any DDL query it gives following error -

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can not perform the operation because the cluster is inactive. Note, that the cluster is considered inactive by default if Ignite Persistent Store is used to let all the nodes join the cluster. To activate the cluster call Ignite.active(true).
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:749)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute0(JdbcThinStatement.java:211)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinStatement.execute(JdbcThinStatement.java:474)
    at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:823)
    at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:733)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:795)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:668)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:373)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:265)
```

How am I supposed to activate the cluster? where do I call Ignite.active(true)?

Note: I am using Gridgrain ignite community edition version 8.7.5 in ubuntu 18.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the `control.sh` script, which you’ll find in the bin directory:

```
control.sh --activate
```

The other ways [are documented](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-activation).